# connect to preferred (saved) network via networksetup without password

Tags: macos, terminal, wifi

I am trying to connect to a secured Wifi via the `networksetup` command (OSX), without re-entering the WPA2 password (assuming the user had entered and saved it before).

I basically want to temporarily switch to another (known) Wifi, then afterwards connect back to the previous one without asking the user for the password.

`networksetup -getairportnetwork en0` returns the current network (so I know where to connect back to)

`networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 WIFI_SSID_I_WANT_TO_JOIN` sounds like my friend, but requires a password. Not specifying a password leads to a failed attempt of connecting without password.

`networksetup -listpreferredwirelessnetworks en0` returns a list of all stored networks that OSX can connect to automatically.

I can't seem to find a way to reconnect to an existing network (from the preferredwirelessnetworks list). Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the following two commands, it is possible to reconnect to a saved network.

```
networksetup -setairportpower en0 off # turn off device en0
networksetup -setairportpower en0 on  # turn on device en0
```

However, this solution cannot specify the network which to connect if there are multiple network configuration saved.